# Removing min operator from max objective

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, reformulation-linearization, bilevel-optimization

I am reading a [paper](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ebzeng/opti/bi_level_reform_online1.pdf) where the authors made the following statement on page 16:
[image]

I wonder why dropping the 'min' operator inside a 'max' objective function is a valid operation here. Any explanation with simple example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Apurba Saha and welcome to or.stackexchange. I think you would get better responses if you link to the paper your are reading. From the context in your question it will be difficult to answer.

Comment: It does not answer your question, but seems the "min" operator is *outside* the "max" objective.